# Access subclass fields from a base class in Java

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance, subclass

I have a base class called *Geometry* from which there exists a subclass *Sphere*:

```
public class Geometry 
{
 String shape_name;
 String material;

 public Geometry()
 {
     System.out.println("New geometric object created.");
 }
}
```

and a subclass:

```
public class Sphere extends Geometry
{
 Vector3d center;
 double radius;

 public Sphere(Vector3d coords, double radius, String sphere_name, String material)
 {
  this.center = coords;
  this.radius = radius;
  super.shape_name = sphere_name;
  super.material = material;
 }
}
```

I have an ArrayList that contains all *Geometry* objects and I want to iterate over it to check whether the data from a text file is read in correctly. Here is my iterator method so far:

```
public static void check()
 {
  Iterator<Geometry> e = objects.iterator();
  while (e.hasNext())
  {
   Geometry g = (Geometry) e.next();
   if (g instanceof Sphere)
   {
    System.out.println(g.shape_name);
    System.out.println(g.material);
   }
  }
 }
```

How do I access and print out the *Sphere's* radius and center fields?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701182/call-a-method-of-subclass-in-java. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The need of the base class to know about the subclass data is pointing out that your abstraction might not be correct. You should take a step back and ask yourself what check is doing and if it needs to be on the base, child or possibly a method of a utility class external to your object model.

Comment: also, you don't need 'super.' everywhere in subclasses, since they inherit the fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to access properties of a subclass,  you're going to have to cast to the subclass.

```
if (g instanceof Sphere)
{
    Sphere s = (Sphere) g;
    System.out.println(s.radius);
    ....
}
```

This isn't the most OO way to do things, though: once you have more subclasses of Geometry you're going to need to start casting to each of those types, which quickly becomes a big mess.  If you want to print the properties of an object, you should have a method on your Geometry object called print() or something along those lines, that will print each of the properties in the object.  Something like this:

```
class Geometry {
   ...
   public void print() {
      System.out.println(shape_name);
      System.out.println(material);
   }
}

class Shape extends Geometry {
   ...
   public void print() {
      System.out.println(radius);
      System.out.println(center);
      super.print();
   }
}
```

This way, you don't need to do the casting and you can just call g.print() inside your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [cast](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) (specifically, [downcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting)):

```
((Sphere) g).radius
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with rwhat, but instead of implementing your own print() function, it might benefit you (and be more Object Oriented) to avoid the downcasts by overriding the toString() function.

```
public class Geometry 
{
 String shape_name;
 String material;

 public Geometry()
 {
     System.out.println("New geometric object created.");
 }

 public String toString() {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      result.append("Shape name: " + shape_name + "\t");
      result.append("Material: " + material + "\t");
      return result.toString();
 }
 public static void check (Geometry[] gList) {
     for (Geometry g: gList) {
         System.out.println(g.toString());
     }
 }
```

Note the `check()` doesn't care whether g is a Sphere or a Cube. This will help minimize the calls to `instanceof`.
Over in Sphere...

```
public class Sphere extends Geometry
 {
  Vector3d center;
  double radius;

  public Sphere(Vector3d coords, double radius, String sphere_name, String material)
  {
   this.center = coords;
   this.radius = radius;
   shape_name = sphere_name;
   super.material = material;
  }
  public String toString() {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      result.append("Radius: " + radius + "\t");
      result.append("Center: " + center.toString() + "\t");
      result.append(super.toString());
      return result.toString();
  }
 }
```

Any new shape (e.g., Cone) would benefit by having the toString() function, but lacking it would just print out Geometry's version.

Answer (score 0):

use instanceof and Cast to the desired subclass.  You might want to make those fields public or the standard idiom of private fields with getters and setters too.