# kotlin override property from interface with subtype

Tags: interface, kotlin, overriding, subtype

I have the following situation:

```
interface AbstractState {...}
interface SubState {...}

interface NiceInterface {
  var currentState: AbstractState
  ...
}
```

Furthermore I have a class which implements this interface.

```
class Class : NiceInterface {
  override var currentState: AbstractState = SubState()
}
```

This implies that I have to write the following at every use of it in the class:

```
(currentState as SubState).doSomething()
```

**Is there a way to avoid the "as SubState" part? Or some kind of smart way to do it?**

Like with generics:

```
interface => val currentStates: List<out AbstractState>
class     => override val currentStates = ArrayList<SubState>()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701182/call-a-method-of-subclass-in-java

Comment: (tl;dr. the top answer there says that you're doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey Romanov said the problem with setter, so there is a workaround, replace var by val:

```
interface AbstractState {}
class SubState : AbstractState{}

interface NiceInterface {
    val currentState: AbstractState
}

class Class : NiceInterface {
    override val currentState: SubState by lazy {
        SubState()
    }
}
```

So now you don't need to cast:

```
currentState.doSomething()
```